# How to find program name(s) of an installed package?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

When I have installed a package using `apt`, is there a way to find out by which command(s) I can run the installed program(s)?

For instance, the package `httpcode` is not available as `httpcode`, and the package description (`apt show httpcode`) does not explain how to run it. How could I have found out that it’s run via `hc` from the command line?

There are two slightly hacky workarounds I found:

1. Assuming that programs are by default installed in `usr/bin`, I ran `ls -ltc | head -n 10` to find recenlty touched files there, and indeed I found `hc`.
2. Similarly to 1, `dpkg -L httpcode` returns a list of files created by installing the package, which also lists `/usr/bin/hc`.

Is there a better solution to this problem that doesn’t hinge upon the intuition of where the program *might* be stored on disk?

I also found that `man httpcode` does open the man page of the program, even though I called it with the package name as argument. Does this always work (if the program provides a manpage)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The locations of files (executables, man-pages and other stuff) should conform [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html) as a rule.

Personally I solve this problem with one of four methods:

1. It is known that executables are placed in the directories declared in `$PATH` environment variable:

   > `$ echo $PATH`
   >   `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

   So one can list all package files with `dpkg --list` (see [`man dpkg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dpkg.1.html) for details) and find files in `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/sbin`, `/usr/games` directories. So we can use the following command:

   > ```
   > $ dpkg -L httpcode | grep -E "/bin/|/sbin/|/usr/games/"
   > /usr/bin/hc
   > ```

   So we can see that `/usr/bin/hc` belongs to this package.
2. List all man-pages:

   > ```
   > $ dpkg -L httpcode | grep "/man/"
   > /usr/share/man/man1
   > /usr/share/man/man1/hc.1.gz
   > ```

   So we can see that we can use `man hc`.
3. For applications with GUI I run search for `*.desktop` files.

   > ```
   > $ dpkg -L httpcode | grep ".desktop"
   > $
   > ```

   In this particular case it will not return anything.

   With some complicated proprietary (or bad-packaged) stuff this method transforms to reading `Exec` variable in the `*.desktop` file - here Telegram is an example:

   > ```
   >  $ dpkg -L telegram | grep ".desktop"
   > /usr/share/applications/telegram.desktop
   >
   > $ grep Exec $(dpkg -L telegram | grep ".desktop")
   > Exec=/opt/telegram/Telegram -- %u
   > ```

   About `Exec` see [Desktop Entry Specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables).
4. For not installed package one can visit https://packages.ubuntu.com and use *Search package directories* here (for [all releases](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=httpcode) or for [selected release](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&searchon=names&keywords=httpcode)), then click on [list of files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/httpcode/filelist) link in the right column of the table:

   > [image: list of files link]

   and one will get the file list:

   > [image: list of files for httpcode package]

   This list may interpreted manually or by using searchbar in the browser.

Comment: Is your first solution always feasible, i.e. do package executables *always* go into some `bin` directory?

Comment: Yes, good-packaged application should conform Filesystem Hierarchy Standard, so its executables should be placed in `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/sbin`.

Comment: Your executable *has* to be in one of the directories of the PATH, or it will not be found typing just the name of the executable in the terminal.

Comment: @vanadium, you are right about `$PATH`. Edited answer to include this approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a shortcut for it to the desktop by right clicking it in the Linux equivalent to the start menu then you can access the properties of said shortcut.

Then just use the end of the command that shortcut uses, for EG I just found Google Chrome's (google-chrome-stable).

BAM there you go. The command to run anything via terminal and/or launcher

Comment: This works for desktop applications, but not every program has a GUI. For those that do, this answer is indeed quicker than N0rbert’s.