# How to know if a package is graphical or command line application?

Tags: command-line, package-management

I am using Ubuntu Server, hence I want to know if a package is GFX or CLI before installing. Wrongly installing GFX apps will cause a lot of dependencies to be fetched, and they will not work anyway (due to the lack of an X server).

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/128524/how-to-list-dependent-packages-reverse-dependencies for a method to check dependencies.

Comment: You could read the `man` page, starting at https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/

Answer (score 3):

For installed application your can follow [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131675/how-to-find-program-names-of-an-installed-package/1131677#1131677).

---

In any case the locations of files (executables, man-pages and other stuff) should conform [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html) as a rule.

For not installed application we can adapt aforementioned method but we will use `apt-file` command instead of `dpkg`.

So we will do the following:

1. Install `apt-file`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install apt-file
   ```
2. Update `apt-file` cache:

   ```
   sudo apt-file update
   ```
3. List all package files with `apt-file list` (see [`man apt-file`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/apt-file.1.html) for details) and find files in `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/sbin`, `/usr/games` directories. So we can use the following command:

   > ```
   > $ sudo apt-file list httpcode | grep -E "/bin/|/sbin/|/usr/games/"
   > httpcode: /usr/bin/hc
   > ```

   So we can see that in this example `/usr/bin/hc` belongs to the package.
4. List all man-pages:

   > ```
   > $ sudo apt-file list httpcode | grep "/man/"
   > httpcode: /usr/share/man/man1/hc.1.gz
   > ```

   So we can see that we can use `man hc`.
5. For applications with GUI I run search for `*.desktop` files:

   > ```
   > $ sudo apt-file list httpcode | grep ".desktop"
   > $
   > ```

   In this particular case it will not return anything.

   But in case of real GUI application such as GNOME Terminal we will try to find its `*.desktop` file

   > ```
   > $ sudo apt-file list gnome-terminal | grep ".desktop$"
   > gnome-terminal: /usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop
   > ```

   And we see that it is found, so it is a GUI application.
6. Also we can check first level of reverse dependencies with command like

   > ```
   > $ apt-cache rdepends gnome-terminal | grep desktop
   > ubuntu-gnome-desktop
   > ubuntu-desktop
   > ubuntukylin-desktop
   > ubuntu-gnome-desktop
   > cinnamon-desktop-environment
   > ubuntu-desktop
   > ```

   - so GNOME Terminal needs DE which is usually ran on Xorg.

Also for not installed package one can visit https://packages.ubuntu.com and use *Search package directories* here (for [all releases](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=httpcode) or for [selected release](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&searchon=names&keywords=httpcode)), then click on [list of files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/httpcode/filelist) link in the right column of the table:

> [image: list of files link]

and one will get the file list:

> [image: list of files for httpcode package]

This list may interpreted manually or by using searchbar in the browser.

Comment: Some CLI applications such as `htop` still create a `.desktop` file, which is a shortcut to run it as console app. I am not really sure about the reverse dependencies method, tried with `apt-cache rdepends blender` and it shows no desktop dependency -- maybe one of its dependencies requires a desktop environment.